# Girl predicts her friends death

Tags: identify-this-movie

A girl and her friends (5 maybe) go to the forest. This girl falls and her whole body shivers. She then sees how her friends are going to die.

After getting up she tells that you are going to die in this place and so on. She tells that someone is following them and only she can see that person (dressed in black).

Her friends start dying in the same way she saw in her visions. She tries to protect herself. When she wakes up, cops and ambulance comes. She tells that she saw a house in the middle of the forest and tells that they killed her friends.

They get arrested. She is then taken in a ambulance, she'll be treated by a doctor. They start talking, when he tells that he is from ___(I don't remember the place), her expression's change and she remembers how she killed her friends in the same way she saw in the dreams.

A cellphone rings in her pocket (at first she tells that she lost it while running). The movie ends and they zoom out of the ambulance, but suddenly they zoom in, we see the girl holding a scissor and a body of doctor nearby).
I think there was a pink cow in the movie!

Comment: Thank you so much..Yes it was the movie I was searching for!! Shrooms :-D O:-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might be looking for the 2007 horror movie **[Shrooms](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0492486/)**

A group of friends go to the forest to go camping and consume magic mushrooms. While collecting them one of the female characters eats a deathcap and proceeds to have premonitions. Later she see's events involving her friends being murdered one by one.

There is a figure dressed in black who I believe was a Monk in the film. I'm not sure if there was a pink cow but there was certainly a cow that talks to one of the characters.

Here is the trailer:

The ending matches your question as well:

> Tara awakes as a Garda helicopter hovers over the camp, and is dispatched into an ambulance as the sole survivor. As her mobile phone rings, she experiences a rapid flashback and realises that the hallucinogenic deathcap mushroom caused her to murder all of her friends. She asks the paramedic for help. Everything becomes quiet until we see her bloody hands holding a pair of bloody scissors which suggests that she has killed the paramedic. The film ends with Tara running in the woods.

Comment: Thank you so much... Yes it was the movie I was searching for!!

Comment: @NatureRocks - no problem & happy to help! :)